# Telescope and not Working with Embedly

Tags: python, telescope, embedly

I have set up a telescope project and want to use embedly to get thumbnails. I am running on localhost.

I got an API key from embedly, placed the key into the telescope settings, and ran the Meteor.call('fetchFeeds') to pull info info. from RSS feeds.

The articles load fine and are posted but I am getting errors of:

```
I20150827-18:02:31.030(-5)?  Couldn't find an Embedly API key! Please add it to your Telescope
enter code here settings or remove the Embedly module.
```

and no thumbnails show up.

I have tired reinstalling telescope, reinstalling module from embedly, and I checked in embedly and I do not have any API requests so I know it is something in telescope. I doubled check API key and generated new one tried that one too.

Can anyone help? I'm at a loss for what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a width and height otherwise the error shows up as not providing an API key.